# Windows 10 Movies & TV app opens up to a black screen with no trackbar or menu options

Tags: windows-10, audio, video, mp4, windows-store-app

figured I'd try my luck asking here, since google gave no helpful results.

It's as the title suggests, Windows 10 Movies & TV app opens up to a black screen with no trackbar or menu options, but **only** when it is set as the default app and open an mp4 from file explorer, or when I select "open with" and click Movies & TV from the file explorer. If I open the Movies & TV app by itself, then open the video from there, it plays without issue.

This is also happening for Groove Music and mp3 files, if I try to open mp3s with Groove from file explorer, it freezes, but if I open Groove, then select my music, it plays.

I've made sure my drivers are all up to date, working, and I have tried re-installing it. The original Windows Media Player works just fine when opening from file explorer.

Hopefully this is just a case of me not understanding something.

And if it's helpful, I have search indexing turned off for file explorer, though I don't know why that'd cause this to happen.

I also have the Event Viewer logs for whenever I try to open an mp4 normally with Movies & TV:

[For all entries: **Log Name: Application**, **Source: ESENT**, 11/21/2022 2:36:42 AM]

- **Event ID: 102**, **Task Category: General**, **Keywords: Classic**. Video.UI (2516,P,98) {B0D29246-ABF1-4FAB-AC52-EF4ACCC15372}: The database engine (10.00.19045.0000) is starting a new instance (0).
- **Event ID: 300**, **Task Category: Logging/Recovery**, **Keywords: Classic**. Video.UI (2516,R,98) {B0D29246-ABF1-4FAB-AC52-EF4ACCC15372}: The database engine is initiating recovery steps.
- **Event ID: 330**, **Task Category: General**, **Keywords: Classic**. Video.UI (2516,R,98) {B0D29246-ABF1-4FAB-AC52-EF4ACCC15372}: The database [C:\Users\Knight542\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.ZuneVideo_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Database\anonymous\EntClientDb.edb] format version is being held back to 8920 (0x22d8) due to application parameter setting of 0x410022D8 (8920 | JET_efvAllowHigherPersistedFormat). Current default engine version: 9180 (0x23dc).]
- **Event ID: 301**, **Task Category: Logging/Recovery**, **Keywords: Classic**. Video.UI (2516,R,98) {B0D29246-ABF1-4FAB-AC52-EF4ACCC15372}: The database engine has finished replaying logfile C:\Users\Knight542\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.ZuneVideo_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Database\anonymous\edb.log.

Processing Stats:
[1] 0.006252 -0.000329 (5) WT +J(CM:0, PgRf:0, Rd:0/0, Dy:0/0, Lg:12168/7) +M(C:0K, Fs:1525, WS:5804K # 5804K, PF:724K # 732K, P:724K).
Log record of type 'AttachDB ' was seen most frequently (1 times)

- **Event ID: 302**, **Task Category: Logging/Recovery**, **Keywords: Classic**. Video.UI (2516,U,98) {B0D29246-ABF1-4FAB-AC52-EF4ACCC15372}: The database engine has successfully completed recovery steps.
- **Event ID: 105**, **Task Category: General**, **Keywords: Classic**. Video.UI (2516,D,0) {B0D29246-ABF1-4FAB-AC52-EF4ACCC15372}: The database engine started a new instance (0). (Time=0 seconds)

Additional Data:
lgposV2[] = 00000003:005D:0000 - 00000003:005F:002B - 00000003:0060:0000 - 00000003:0060:0000 (00000000:0000:0000)
cReInits = 1

Internal Timing Sequence:
[1] 0.000644 +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:167, WS:644K # 644K, PF:2836K # 2828K, P:2836K)
[2] 0.000264 +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:131, WS:512K # 512K, PF:276K # 276K, P:276K)
[3] 0.000011 +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:3, WS:12K # 12K, PF:64K # 64K, P:64K)
[4] 0.000112 +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:45, WS:176K # 176K, PF:232K # 232K, P:232K)
[5] 0.002472 +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:378, WS:1484K # 1484K, PF:1028K # 1028K, P:1028K)
[6] 0.001284 +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:215, WS:840K # 840K, PF:244K # 244K, P:244K)
[7] 0.001779 -0.000002 (2) WT +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:950, WS:3780K # 3780K, PF:2872K # 2872K, P:2872K)
[8] 0.007995 -0.000329 (5) WT +J(CM:0, PgRf:0, Rd:0/0, Dy:0/0, Lg:12168/7) +M(C:0K, Fs:1934, WS:7400K # 7400K, PF:1200K # 1208K, P:1200K)
[9] 0.000385 +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:25, WS:100K # 100K, PF:56K # 48K, P:56K)
[10] 0.000957 +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:36, WS:-1904K # 112K, PF:-1948K # 96K, P:-1948K)
[11] 0.000017 +J(CM:0, PgRf:0, Rd:0/0, Dy:0/0, Lg:49/1) +M(C:0K, Fs:3, WS:12K # 0K, PF:0K # 0K, P:0K)
[12] 0.010233 -0.010173 (2) WT +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:1564, WS:5956K # 4140K, PF:2496K # 584K, P:2496K)
[13] 0.019846 -0.000242 (2) CM -0.015683 (19) WT +J(CM:2, PgRf:2, Rd:0/2, Dy:0/0, Lg:8759/5) +M(C:0K, Fs:1384, WS:3116K # 4976K, PF:424K # 2344K, P:424K)
[14] 0.000011 +J(0)
[15] 0.000006 +J(0)
[16] 0.000097 +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:2, WS:0K # 0K, PF:0K # 0K, P:0K).

- **Event ID: 330**, **Task Category: General**, **Keywords: Classic**. Video.UI (2516,D,50) {B0D29246-ABF1-4FAB-AC52-EF4ACCC15372}: The database [C:\Users\Knight542\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.ZuneVideo_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Database\anonymous\EntClientDb.edb] format version is being held back to 8920 (0x22d8) due to application parameter setting of 0x410022D8 (8920 | JET_efvAllowHigherPersistedFormat). Current default engine version: 9180 (0x23dc).
- **Event ID: 641**, **Task Category: General**, **Keywords: Classic**. Video.UI (2516,D,50) {B0D29246-ABF1-4FAB-AC52-EF4ACCC15372}: The log format feature version 8940 (0x22ec - 8.6.20) could not be used due to the current log format 8.5.16, controlled by the parameter 0x410022D8 (8920 | JET_efvAllowHigherPersistedFormat).
- **Event ID: 326**, **Task Category: General**, **Keywords: Classic**. Video.UI (2516,D,50) {B0D29246-ABF1-4FAB-AC52-EF4ACCC15372}: The database engine attached a database (1, C:\Users\Knight542\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.ZuneVideo_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Database\anonymous\EntClientDb.edb). (Time=0 seconds)

Saved Cache: 0 0
Additional Data: lgposAttach = 00000003:0062:0268,
dbv = 1568.20.0

Internal Timing Sequence:
[1] 0.000001 +J(0)
[2] 0.000259 +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:21, WS:20K # 0K, PF:8K # 0K, P:8K)
[3] 0.002604 -0.000296 (5) WT +J(CM:0, PgRf:0, Rd:0/0, Dy:0/0, Lg:3480/2) +M(C:0K, Fs:193, WS:764K # 0K, PF:60K # 0K, P:60K)
[4] 0.000119 +J(0) +M(C:0K, Fs:16, WS:64K # 0K, PF:4K # 0K, P:4K)
[5] -
[6] -
[7] -
[8] 0.000974 -0.000234 (2) CM +J(CM:2, PgRf:2, Rd:14/2, Dy:0/0, Lg:0/0) +M(C:0K, Fs:13, WS:44K # 0K, PF:144K # 0K, P:144K)
[9] 0.006258 -0.000011 (5) CM -0.006075 (1) WT +J(CM:5, PgRf:23, Rd:0/5, Dy:0/0, Lg:0/0) +M(C:0K, Fs:450, WS:1620K # 484K, PF:420K # 0K, P:420K)
[10] 0.000291 -0.000003 (1) CM +J(CM:1, PgRf:40, Rd:0/1, Dy:0/0, Lg:0/0) +M(C:0K, Fs:16, WS:56K # 56K, PF:64K # 0K, P:64K)
[11] 0.000007 +J(CM:0, PgRf:1, Rd:0/0, Dy:0/0, Lg:0/0) +M(C:0K, Fs:8, WS:32K # 32K, PF:0K # 0K, P:0K)
[12] 0.000022 +J(CM:0, PgRf:42, Rd:0/0, Dy:0/0, Lg:0/0) +M(C:0K, Fs:9, WS:36K # 36K, PF:0K # 0K, P:0K)
[13] 0.0 +J(0)
[14] 0.0 +J(0)
[15] 0.000003 +J(CM:0, PgRf:1, Rd:0/0, Dy:0/0, Lg:0/0) +M(C:0K, Fs:1, WS:4K # 4K, PF:0K # 0K, P:0K).

- **Event ID: 330**, **Task Category: General**, **Keywords: Classic**. Video.UI (2516,D,2) {B0D29246-ABF1-4FAB-AC52-EF4ACCC15372}: The database [C:\Users\Knight542\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.ZuneVideo_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Database\anonymous\tmp.edb] format version is being held back to 8920 (0x22d8) due to application parameter setting of 0x410022D8 (8920 | JET_efvAllowHigherPersistedFormat). Current default engine version: 9180 (0x23dc).

[ End of Event Viewer logs ]

I've tried:

- Reinstalling Movies & TV and Groove Music
- Double click the mp4 from file explorer while Movies & TV is the
  default mp4 program. Result: Black window with no video playing.
- Context menu "open with" and selecting Movies & TV from file explorer
  on an mp4 while Movies & TV is set to default mp4 program. Result:
  Black window with no video playing.
- Opening Movies & TV from the start menu while movies and TV is set to
  default mp4 program, then opening the video from the library. Result:
  Video Plays.
- Setting Windows Media Player as the default mp4 program and double
  clicking from file explorer on an mp4. Result: Video plays.
- Setting Windows Media Player as default mp4 program and Context menu
  "open with" and selecting Windows Media Player to open an mp4.
  Result: Video plays.
- Restarting my laptop "fixes" the issue temporarily, but it comes back
  after a few days.

One thing I've noticed, **only** for opening Movies&Tv / Groove *first*, some videos do play, and some don't. The only ones that play, are ones that have their folder directed to in the apps.

I also remember making a similar post to this last month, but it seems to be gone? Probably because I forgot to check back in on it. I know I can use an alternate app, and I am (the classic Windows Media Player), but I'd like to get to the bottom of this, because I actually quite like Movies&TV and Groove's look, and I'm paranoid about things not working, as last time this happened, it coincided with my hard drive failing. I sincerely thank you all for any help you can offer.

Edit (3:00 am): There is no Event viewer entries for when Groove freezes, or at least none that I can find. I've also just noticed that when this issue occurs, I can also no longer navigate the Photos app with arrow keys, I have to close the image, then open the next one, instead of cycling to the next one in the app.

Update (8:30 am): Thanks to @harrymc, remembered SFC and DISM. Ran SFC /scannow, and it found some corrupted files (which it said it fixed), followed by Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth, to make sure that the source SFC was pulling from was nice and good, then ran SFC /scannow again for good measure, this time coming back with no integrity issues. Fingers crossed that this fixed it, I really want to be optimistic.

Comment: I'd like to apologize if it seems very run-on and disorganized, tech issues that I can't find any working solutions for really make my anxiety spike to the roof. Ideally, I'd love to fix this issue, but just confirmation that it won't cause any catostrophic issues should I just move on to using the original Windows Media Player would help calm my heart.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Ran it overnight @harrymc! First SFC scan said that it detected corrupted files, and successfully repaired them. I ran the DISM Image cleanup afterwards, then did a second SFC scan and it said there were no integrity issues. Fingers crossed that this fixes it?

Also, should I attach the log from the scan that found the corrupted files to the body of my original post?

Comment: Keep the log, but no point in examining it for the moment. If the problem comes back, the next step is to [Do a Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), which is the same as a major Windows upgrade and keeps all apps and data.

Comment: Will keep that in mind, hopefully the issue did get fixed with that. I know the repair keeps all your stuff, unlike a reinstall, but it's still quite nerve-wracking. Thanks again for all the help so far!

Comment: Let me know if the problem seems solved for a few days, and I'll put up an answer.

Comment: Just an update for you @harrymc It seemed to have fixed it over the past two days, but I suddenly started getting problems with explorer.exe sourced to faulty module dui70.dll, and photos app sourced to faulty module kernelbase.dll.

So I'm going to try to repair windows using the media creation tool on a usb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First advice was to test Windows integrity by running :

- [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
- [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)

This found and fixed some problems, and everything seemed right for a
couple of days, then problems began again.

This very frequently is required as the next step, because although
DISM and SFC do well for detecting errors, they are not very efficient
at fixing them.

In that case, stronger measures are required, in the form of
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
This is the same as doing a major Windows upgrade and it keeps
all apps and data, while setting all Windows components to a
coherent state.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to have fixed the issue, you're a real lifesaver harry!

Just a follow up question, how can I tell if the Repair worked properly? I didn't get any kind of messages, I left it alone for a few hours, then came back to my laptop having logged me in, but missing my desktop background. Sorry if this seems like an obvious question, but I'm having a bit of trouble thinking straight due to the stress.